# Problem with Types in typescript: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript

I am having a problem with Types in the backend of my application. The application has a data of various patients for doctor to manage. I am trying to add a new entry into an existing patient and I am getting this error:

```
Argument of type '{ type: "Hospital" | "OccupationalHealthcare" | "HealthCheck"; description: string; date: string; specialist: string; diagnosisCodes?: string[] | undefined; id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Entry'.
  Type '{ type: "Hospital" | "OccupationalHealthcare" | "HealthCheck"; description: string; date: string; specialist: string; diagnosisCodes?: string[] | undefined; id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'HealthCheckEntry'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"Hospital" | "OccupationalHealthcare" | "HealthCheck"' is not assignable to type '"HealthCheck"'.
        Type '"Hospital"' is not assignable to type '"HealthCheck"'.ts(2345)
```

I checked everything and it seems like the code should be working. Can anyone help me with this? The error is on this row: `patientData.find(p => p.id === patientId)?.entries.push(newEntry);`

```
import patientData from '../../data/patients'

import { Patient, NonSensitivePatientData, NewPatient, NewEntry } from '../types';

const patients: Array<Patient> = patientData

const getPatients = (): Patient[] => {
  return patients;
};

const addEntry = (entry: NewEntry, patientId: string): Patient | undefined => {
  
  const newEntry = {
    id: 1,
    ...(entry as NewEntry)
  }

  patientData.find(p => p.id === patientId)?.entries.push(newEntry);

  const patient = patients.find(p => p.id === patientId);

  console.log(newEntry);

  return patient;
}

export default {
  addEntry
};
```

Here are my types:

```
interface BaseEntry {
  id: string;
  description: string;
  date: string;
  specialist: string;
  diagnosisCodes?: Array<Diagnose['code']>;
}

export enum HealthCheckRating {
  "Healthy" = 0,
  "LowRisk" = 1,
  "HighRisk" = 2,
  "CriticalRisk" = 3
}

export interface HealthCheckEntry extends BaseEntry {
  type: "HealthCheck";
  healthCheckRating?: HealthCheckRating;
}

interface Discharge {
  date: string;
  criteria: string;
}

export interface HospitalEntry extends BaseEntry {
  type: "Hospital";
  discharge: Discharge;
}

interface SickLeave {
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}

export interface OccupationalHealthcareEntry extends BaseEntry {
  type: "OccupationalHealthcare";
  employerName: string;
  sickLeave?: SickLeave;
}

export type Entry =
  | HospitalEntry
  | OccupationalHealthcareEntry
  | HealthCheckEntry;

export interface Patient {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  ssn: string;
  gender: Gender;
  occupation: string;
  entries: Entry[];
}

export type NewEntry = Omit<Entry, 'id'>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out: I had to do "type assertion". Type "NewEntry" does not have an id property, but I am adding an id to "entry", this process creates newEntry variable. Now I had to change it's type from NewEntry to Entry, it happens like this:

```
patientData.find(p => p.id === patientId)?.entries.push(newEntry as Entry);
```